# Restrict styling of an ordered list with a class on the OL

Tags: css, html-lists

I need to restrict the styling of an ordered list by adding a class on the OL.  (I can't use a parent div class.)

`<ol class="mylist_1_a">`

I have a working example, with the first level using the decimal type and the second using lower-alpha with a right parenthesis instead of a period.  http://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/2b7jxLqr/

However, if I add the OL class to my css it breaks.  It should be straight forward, but it's not.

```
ol.mylist_1_a {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.mylist_1_a li {
  display: table;
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}
.mylist_1_a li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 0.6em;
}
.mylist_1_a li li {
  margin: 0;
}
.mylist_1_a li li:before {
  content: counter(item, lower-alpha) ") ";
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "it breaks" is not a sufficient enough description to be able to help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you also need your `<ol>` style on the second one. I just put the same class on the second one.

```css
.test {width: 300px; background-color: #eee;}

ol.mylist_1_a{
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.mylist_1_a li {
  display: table;
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

.mylist_1_a li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 0.6em;
}

.mylist_1_a li li {
  margin: 0;
}


.mylist_1_a li li:before {
  content: counter(item, lower-alpha) ") ";
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <ol class="mylist_1_a">
    <li>First item
      <ol class="mylist_1_a">
        <li>Some very long text that goes on the next line</li>
        <li>Short text</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Second item and some very long text that goes on the next line</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this!  Is there no way that the parent class on the first OL can style the child OL as well?  I am not sure that I can add the class on the child OL in the CMS block I have.

Comment: You can sibling your second ol like this ol > ol

Comment: I could not get ol > ol to work.  But I this did the trick:  .mylist_1_a li ol
http://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/mpzjkn6c/ 
Thank you so much for getting me on the right track!!!

Comment: You are welcome. Sometimes targeting in css is messy :)